# How to write below equation in appropriate mathematical form?

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives

Given is my equation in words that I wanted to convert in mathematical form.

Per year growth in number of chocolates of person i = chocolates granted to i +  (chocolates give by all j to i - chocolates given by i to all j)

The last term (chocolates give by all j to i - chocolates given by i to all j), I am able to write it as eqn can be shown as [See EQN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zu8oZ.png)  , here N(i) represents all friends of i that are j's.

The chocolates granted to i value is constant value same for each year.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The word below is a preposition or an adverb: one cannot say "the below equation". Even if it's become common in math, it is really very, very bad grammar — the worse is that it's easily fixable. "The equation below" works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering:

- $J_i$ annual growth of chocolates per person $i$
- $G_{ii}$ chocolate granted to $i$
- $G_{ij}$ chocolate given (or granted) to $i$ by $j$

I would write it like this:

$$J_i = G_{ii} + \sum_{j \in \mathcal{N}(i)} (G_{ij} - G_{ji})$$
where $\mathcal{N}(i)$ indicates the friends of person $i$. Clearly I assume that if $j$ is friend of $i$, also $i$ if friend of $j$, otherwise the sum would change.

Comment: As $J_{i}$ is annual growth rate can we also write in  derivate form?

Comment: I think you can, like some sort of ratio between your growth and the time

Comment: okay, Thanks for your response.